# Why does 'rutils.iter' seem to work differently than 'iterate'?

Tags: loops, common-lisp

(I understand this might turn out to be library-specific, in which case feel free to close it down, I'm asking in case the reason is language-specific)

Both the `rutilsx.iter` and the `iterate` libraries (as available through Quicklisp) seem to present the same ["Don't Loop, Iterate"](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/iterate/doc/index.html#Top) library.

Yet, while the latter "just works", the former doesn't. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, I don't know what.

So this works:

```
CL-USER> num-list
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

CL-USER> (iter (for el in num-list)
               (when (>= el 3)
                 (collect el)))
(3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

But this doesn't:

```
CL-USER> (rutilsx.iter:iter (for el in num-list)
               (when (>= el 3)
                 (collect el)))
```

(it gives errors about everything being undefined ... why?)

I tried `macroexpand`ing each of them, this is what I see:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(iter (for el in num-list)
               (when (>= el 3)
                 (collect el))))
(LET* ((#:LIST21 NIL)
       (EL NIL)
       (#:RESULT20 NIL)
       (#:END-POINTER22 NIL)
       (#:TEMP23 NIL))
  (BLOCK NIL
    (TAGBODY
      (PROGN (SETQ #:LIST21 NUM-LIST))
     LOOP-TOP-NIL
      (PROGN
       (IF (ENDP #:LIST21)
           (GO LOOP-END-NIL))
       (SETQ EL (CAR #:LIST21))
       (SETQ #:LIST21 (CDR #:LIST21))
       (IF (>= EL 3)
           (PROGN
            (PROGN
             (SETQ #:TEMP23 (LIST EL))
             (SETQ #:END-POINTER22
                     (IF #:RESULT20
                         (SETF (CDR #:END-POINTER22) #:TEMP23)
                         (SETQ #:RESULT20 #:TEMP23)))
             #:RESULT20))
           NIL))
      (PROGN)
      (GO LOOP-TOP-NIL)
     LOOP-END-NIL
      (PROGN))
    #:RESULT20))
T
```

vs.

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(rutilsx.iter:iter (for el in num-list)
               (when (>= el 3)
                 (collect el))))
(LET* ()
  (BLOCK NIL
    (TAGBODY
     LOOP-TOP-NIL
      (FOR EL IN NUM-LIST)
      (IF (>= EL 3)
          (PROGN (COLLECT EL))
          NIL)
      (GO LOOP-TOP-NIL))
    NIL))
T
```

(Clearly the second version "half-way" works, instead of doing *nothing*)

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use keywords for the syntactic identifiers

Comment: Yes, the following works!

```
CL-USER> (rutilsx.iter:iter (:for el :in num-list)
               (when (>= el 3)
                 (:collect el)))
```

But (1) it doesn't work when I use `:when` instead of `when`, and (2) more generally, why did the corresponding version with `iterate` not have this problem?

Comment: If you read the comments at the top of the [source file](https://github.com/vseloved/rutils/blob/master/contrib/iter.lisp), it says that only keywords are allowed for the identifiers. `WHEN` is the regular CL macro, so it shouldn't be a keyword.

Comment: Right, I should have RTFM, sorry about that; thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Keywords**

The `rutilsx.iter` library uses keywords for `ITERATE`'s syntactic identifiers.

**WHEN**

`WHEN` is no `ITERATE` syntactic identifier. It is the usual Common Lisp `cl:when`. Thus you can't use a keyword `:when`.

**ITERATE clauses can be inside Lisp forms**

What's a bit surprising for those used to `LOOP`, the `ITERATE` macro allows clauses like `COLLECT` inside Lisp expressions.

LOOP:

```
(loop for el in '(1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3)
      when (>= el 3)
      collect el)
```

Above needs `WHEN ...` to be a clause of the `LOOP` macro.

ITERATE:

```
(iter (for el in num-list)
      (when (>= el 3)
        (collect el)))
```

In above form, `WHEN` is the normal `CL:WHEN` and the `iterate` macro *walks* into its subforms, when it looks for clauses, like the `collect` in this example.